# Keras not finding images through 'flow_from_dataframe'

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying run a ImageDataGenerator using the code below but I keep running into the error;

"Found 0 validated image filenames."

The most obvious point would be an error in the paths (directory and x_col) but I'm able to read the files using imageio/pydicom with the corresponding paths from the code below. Another point could be the fact that I am trying to read Dicom (DCM) images but I cannot find a source to substantiate this probability.

I have been trying solutions for the last hour and am starting to get *slightly* frustrated. What am I missing?

```
train_data = train_data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = data_input,
    directory = input_dir_im,
    x_col = 'path',
    y_col = class_list,
    target_size = input_tensor,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = False,
    class_mode = 'raw',
    )
```

Comment: ImageDataGenerator obviously does not support DCM images, it only supports standard image file formats like PNG, JPEG, etc

Comment: It appears I overlooked this basic point while falling down the rabbit hole...*sigh*.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dr.Snoopy pointed out, Keras only supports standard image file formats.